# Hiding windows created by main window in electron

Tags: javascript, electron, puppeteer

I'm web scraping in electron using puppeteer and whenever I encounter a download button with an onclick event triggering a 'downloadCourseDocs(....)' function, I emulate a click on it. This, in a normal browser opens a new tab for downloading that file.

In electron, I see that it opens a new blank, white window.

How do I prevent this/ hide the newly created window?

I tried playing around with the "browser-window-created" and "new-window-for-tab" events on the app and window instance but to no luck.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking for an answer to this, here's how I fixed it:

```
window.webContents.on("did-create-window", (windowCreated) => windowCreated.hide());
```

You could probably also close the window.